# Can I force the dropdown view of a spinner to stay visible on orientation changes?

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, spinner

I don't know if it's clear from the title what I asked, so here are some steps to reproduce (assuming you have a layout with a spinner):

1. Tap on the spinner > dropdown list opens.
2. Rotate the device from portrait to landscape (or vice-versa) > the list is closing.

My problem is that I would like to keep the list opened after rotating the device. I know that this is usually possible if overriding **onConfigurationChanged**, but I have defined a different layout for landscape mode, so in my onConfigurationChanged method I have to call **setContentView** and set the adapter for the landscape spinner, which closes the dropdown view that was opened in portrait mode.

Is there a way I could prevent the dropdown list from closing or perhaps forcing it to show after rotating the device?

Answer (score 6):

I found a very ugly solution to this (the 'action' takes place in the **onConfigurationChanged** method):

1. Before calling **setContentView**, check if the dropdown view is shown **(*)** and if so, save the position that is currently selected in the spinner (`int pos = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()`).
2. After calling **setContentView** and setting the spinner adapter, if the dropdown view was shown in step 1, force the dropdown view to show by calling **performClick** on the spinner:

   ```
   spinner.setSelection(pos);// this way we make sure that the same item
                             // remains selected after rotating the device
   spinner.performClick(); //show the dropdown view
   ```

**(*)** Checking if the dropdown view is shown is the trickier part. I haven't found (yet) a method that lets me know whether the dropdown view is shown, so I had to do the following:

- Hold the spinner's pressed state in a boolean variable (named, for example, **isClicked**).
- Set an **onTouchListener**  for the spinner and in the **onTouch** method set **isClicked** to true (when tapping the spinner, the dropdwon view opens, so **isClicked == true** means that the dropdown view is shown).
- Override **onKeyDown** or **onKeyUp** and when back button is pressed, if **isClicked** is true, set it to false (I assumed that pressing back with **isClicked==true** means closing the dropdown view).
- Use the value of **isClicked** in **onConfigurationChanged** method to check if the dropdown view is shown.

Like I said, it's an ugly fix, but it's the only one I could come up with until now. If anybody has other ideas, please post them.

Answer (score 0):

By default the behavior on switching from portrait to landscape is restart your Activity. So, you can save the spinner state to somewhere, for example to SharedPreferences and read it when restarting the activity(in onCreate() or onResume()) methods.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I have already tried with onSaveInstanceState/onRestoreInstanceState for my spinner and it's not really helpful in this situation. It only saves the item that was selected and not the fact that the list was opened. Is there another way to save the spinner's state (something that includes the fact that the dropdown view was opened)? Or perhaps I can save the dropdownview's state somehow?